# SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement.BindParameter

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, xamarin.android

I have a simple insert statement to a table in an SQLite database on MonoDroid.

When inserting to the database, it says

> SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement.BindParameter

I think there is either a bug, or the error message is misleading. Because I only have 5 parameters and I am providing 5 parameters, so I cannot see how this be right.

My code is below, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [User] (UserPK ,Name ,Password ,Category ,ContactFK) VALUES ( @UserPK , @Name , @Password , @Category , @ContactFK)";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Name", "Has"));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Password", "Has"));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Cateogry", ""));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@ContactFK", DBNull.Value));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@UserPK", DbType.Guid) {Value = Guid.NewGuid()});
            var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return = result > 0 ;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    LogError(exception);
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your spelling for `@Category` in INSERT statement is different from added parameter. 
You have:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Cateogry", ""));
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                           //@Category
```

Where it should be:

Modify your statement to:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Category", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this was embarrassing :)

Comment: Wish the error message would contain the *name* of the parameter that was not sufficiently supplied.

Answer (score 4):

This has already been answered correctly, but I wish to add, for further information:

This specific SQLite error string can also be generated if any of the @Parameters are spelled differently in the INSERT statement vs the AddWithValue or .Add(new SqliteParameter... statements.